# Subset rows in data.table if all specified columns match a criterion

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` 'a' and a vector of column names 'cols':

```
a <- data.table(n = c("case1", "case2", "case3"), x = c(0,2,5), y = c(1,1,4), z = c(1,1,0))
cols <- c("x", "y", "z")
a
#        n x y z
# 1: case1 0 1 1
# 2: case2 2 1 1
# 3: case3 5 4 0
```

I want to select rows from `a` were *all* values in the columns whose names are saved in `cols` are above 0.

Desired result:

```
#        n x y z
# 2: case2 2 1 1
```

I used `apply` in combination with `all()`, but I think there is a much faster way with `data.table` to do this. My original data is of course much much larger and `cols` contains up 80 column names. Thanks for your help!

---

***Benchmarks***

Thank you for your answers! All of them work but obviously with different performance. Please check the comments of the accepted answer for a benchmark. The fastest way to do this is, indeed:

```
a[ a[, do.call(pmin, .SD) > 0, .SDcols = cols] ]
```

I also replicated the benchmarks for the different solutions using the `rbenchmark` package and my original dataset with slightly different parameters (880,000 rows, 64 columns from which 62 are selected) and can confirm the speed ranking of the different solutions (10 replications have been made):

`` z[z[, !Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `<`, 11)),.SDcols = col.names]] ``: 3.32 sec

`z[apply(z[, col.names, with = FALSE], 1, function(x) all(x > 10))]`: 37.41 sec

`z[ z[, do.call(pmin, .SD) > 10, .SDcols = col.names] ]`: 2.03 sec

`` z[rowSums(z[, lapply(.SD, `<`, 11), .SDcols = col.names]) == 0] ``: 4.84 sec

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `.SDcols`.  Specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) check whether it is equal 0, get the sum of each row with `Reduce`, negate (`!`) to get a logical vector which returns TRUE when there are no 0 elements and use that to subset the rows of 'a'

```
a[a[, !Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `<=`, 0)),.SDcols = cols]]
#       n x y z
#1: case2 2 1 1
```

Or as @Frank mentioned in the comments, `pmin` can be used as well

```
a[a[, do.call(pmin, .SD), .SDcols = cols]>0]
```

Comment: A similar option: `a[ a[, do.call(pmin, .SD) > 0, .SDcols=cols] ]` ... actually, I guess yours might need adjustment considering the OP wants "above zero" not "not zero".

Comment: FYI, if you are corious, for 1e7 rows and functions as below:
f1. `a[rowSums(a[, lapply(.SD, "<=", 0), .SDcols = cols]) == 0]`
f2. `a[a[, !Reduce("+", lapply(.SD, "<=", 0)), .SDcols = cols]]`
f3. `a[apply(a[, cols, with = FALSE], 1, function(x) all(x>0))]`
**f4. `a[ a[, do.call(pmin, .SD) > 0, .SDcols=cols] ]`**
median execution times are: f1 = 684 ms, f2 = 539 ms, f3 = 32724 ms, **f4 = 260 ms**.

Comment: Ah, to be sure I have added a fourth column: `ignore = sample(-10:10, n, replace = TRUE)`, which of course was ignored by all functions.

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
a[rowSums(a[, lapply(.SD, `<=`, 0), .SDcols=cols])==0]
#       n x y z
#1: case2 2 1 1
```

It selects the rows for which there are no `cols` columns with a value below or equal to zero (you can also use condition x>0 and check for `==length(cols)` if you prefer).

Answer (score 1):

You can `apply` row-wise and then check if `all` the values in that row is greater than 0.

```
a[apply(a[, cols, with = FALSE], 1, function(x) all(x>0))]

#       n x y z
#1: case2 2 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you! But why does this work?!? Obviously, column n is also selected here. But why is "case2" > 0? Also, there could be other columns apart from x, y and z that shouldn't be included into the all()-test. So I somehow need the cols variable to be included...

Comment: If you only want `cols` variable to be included you can specify that. I have updated the answer.

Comment: `apply(..., 1, ...)` inside a data.table is pretty ugly :-/

Comment: Hmmm..I thought so. I was a bit reluctant to add this as an answer as the question was tagged with `data.table`. Time to learn it maybe.

Comment: And you will probably need to use either `a[, cols, with = FALSE]` or `a[, .SD, .SDcols = cols]` to run this.

Comment: Every day is a school day! `data.table()` is sometimes weird, but its performance is amazing.

Comment: base R answers are always good, but the best as a supplement to the answer using solution for particular tag